# On a sum involving fractional part of an integer

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

I was interested in estimating the sum of the form
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{N} \{ \sqrt{j} \}.
$$
I was wondering if there is a reference or maybe some one could
help me figure out what to do.
Thanks!
$\{ \alpha\}$ denotes the fractional part of the real number $\alpha$.

Comment: Naively, $\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$ of the integers from $1$ to $N$ are perfect squares, so an upper bound is $N-\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired sum is equal to $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^N \sqrt{j}\right) - \left(\sum_{j=1}^N \lfloor \sqrt{j}\rfloor\right)$$

The second sum is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10230/73324) as $(N+1)a - \frac{a^3}{3} - \frac{a^2}{2} - \frac{a}{6}$, where $a=\lfloor \sqrt{N+1}\rfloor$.

The first sum may be estimated by an integral as follows
$$\frac{2}{3}N^{3/2}=\int_0^N\sqrt{x}dx < \left(\sum_{j=1}^N \sqrt{j}\right) < \int_1^{N+1} \sqrt{x}dx=\frac{2}{3}((N+1)^{3/2}-1)$$

The difference between the upper and lower estimates is $O(\sqrt{N})$, which isn't too bad I think.  With care the integrals can be refined, sharpening the estimates.

Comment: My pleasure. $~~$