# Sum of Floor of Square Root: $S = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor$

Tags: summation, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor.
$$

Hello, I´m trying to solve this summation. I was able to get
$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}
$$
for non perfect square numbers and
$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + 1
$$
for perfect square numbers.
But I´m clueless how to continue. I was thinking about some function which is 1 for square numbers and 0 for others and and make only one recurrence. But I 
don´t think that´s the way...

Comment: What is the relation between $S, k$, and $a_n$?

Comment: Related post: [Find a formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669460/find-a-formula-for-sum-limits-k-1n-lfloor-sqrtk-rfloor) (BTW this post was shown among related questions on the right.) Maybe also [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10183/floor-of-square-root-summation-problem).